# How to display a Dialog on top of another Dialog?

Tags: roku, brightscript

With on-device authentication support, I open `KeyboardDialog` with pre-filled user email address. When user clicks `Continue` button, I want to verify email address and show error message if it is not correct, similar like on the picture. Haven't found any solution on how to show dialog on top of another dialog. Thanks in advance.

[Example screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E7XBP.jpg)

Comment: I don't know exactly. how it's working. This sample available on github https://github.com/rokudev/samples/tree/master/roku%20pay Zip FileName: ChannelStore_SignupFlow.zip. I hope this is helpful.

Comment: @NikunjChaklasiya unfortunately these examples do not work as expected. The workflow I've chosen is to maintain the dialogs flow with the bi-directional link list and show them one by one.

Comment: Did you found a solution to this?

Comment: @NikunjChaklasiya nah. decided to go with the solution above

Answer (score 1):

You would need to open/close the dialog from the mainscene in the main thread.
i.e :
`parentNode = m.top.getScene() parentNode.dialog = dialog`

Answer (score 0):

Just show the dialog in the click of that button and make keyword focus as false.and dialog focus as true.its work